# Trouble with RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I'm having some trouble using RelativeLayout.

I want 4 equally sized spaces oriented horizontally.  This is simple enough when you contain them inside a LinearLayout.  You just set their layout_width to "fill_parent" and their layout_weight to "1".  However, how can I accomplish this inside a RelativeLayout?  I don't know the width dimension of each of the 4 spaces as Android phones can be of differing sizes and I want this to be dynamic.

Ideas?

In case there's an alternate solution, here is what I'm trying to do: Here's a quick mockup I drew. I have a toolbar and the first time the user visits the screen I'd like some images to lay over the top of the screen. Each of these images contains an arrow with some text associated with whatever the arrow is intended to point to. So you can see how I need to place the image relative to one of the 4 spaces and the images themselves can extend the width of the space. http://i42.tinypic.com/2yxi683.jpg

Update: I've found a solution, though I would like to find a better one.  I've grabbed the 4 Views programmatically, determined the display's width, divided that number by 4, and set the width of each View to that value.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to post a mockup of what you really want for the layout in case there's another approach you can use that someone can come up with, but if you really can't use the nested LinearLayout approach, you're probably going to have to create a custom layout.

Comment: Here's a quick mockup I drew.  I have a toolbar and the first time the user visits the screen I'd like some images to lay over the top of the screen.  Each of these images contains an arrow with some text associated with whatever the arrow is intended to point to.  So you can see how I need to place the image relative to one of the 4 spaces and the images themselves can extend the width of the space. http://i42.tinypic.com/2yxi683.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Create a LinearLayout and place the 4 view in the LinearLayout. Then just add the LinearLayout to the RelativeLayout. That is the easiest way.

Comment: This will not work for me.  I need the 4 spaces to be directly inside the RelativeLayout so that I can overlay other Views relative to the 4 spaces.

Comment: Then use a TableLayout. That is your only other option, I believe.

Comment: That will not work either.  Basically I have images I want to appear on the screen that look like theyre hovering over the screen.  These are helper images that contain an arrow and some text describing what the arrow points to.  I have a toolbar with 4 evenly spaced buttons, so I need a way to make these helper images that pop up point directly at the buttons.  These images are wider than the individual columns.

Comment: What would probably do you better, then, is customising RL's on draw. I would put the hovering images there somehow.